# Pagetab not shown for public Users

Tags: facebook, tabs

I create an App for Facebook Users, but for public Users this Tab isn't visible on an Facebook Tab.

This App is't run in Sandboxmode and work in an Testcase on an other public Page as Tab also for all other Facebookusers.

The Pagetab createt with the documentet Workflow in the Facebook Documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Is there a revision Workflow available to add an Pagetab on an Facebookpage or an quantity restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the correct app to your fan page? And did you enable the App Box in the timeline so users can click on it? Go to `Edit Page` on your page and click on `Apps` on the left menu. Double check that your app is there. Then click on `Edit Settings` make make sure the tab has been added to your page.

Answer (score 0):

**USE this way**

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next={YOUR_Domain_URL}

then you will get a list pages you can select one ,,there the app will get a link to load

Ref :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/